# XAMPP: error when starting tomcat

Tags: tomcat, xampp

I tried to start tomcat with xampp 1.8.3 on xampp control panel v3.2.1 but i get this error:

Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors, return code: 1
Make sure you have Java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free
Check the "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information

can somebody help me please? i'm using windows 7

ps. sorry if my english is not/will not be perfect

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I found that it's possible to install Tomcat services and start it by directly running `tomcat\tomcat_service_install.bat` for installing, and then `catalina_start.bat` for starting.

By inserting `echo` in the `bat`, I found that the control panel doesn't start any of these `.bat` files.  I don't know why.

PS Very strange, but all work now :) It was appear also very similar problem with filezilla, but I need it, so I try to find solution again, and with partly success. 
I remove both services manually from window services vith use 
sc delete "servicename" 
After this, I was try to start Filezilla and tomcat, WITHOUT installing services< and both started ! 
So, uninstall this services, (checkbox of it's may have red cross in control panel, but uninstall manually, as I describe), and then, filezilla and tomcat became work !

Answer (score 1):

I hava similar problem with you. When I start my Xampp panel, it prompt me that 3306 port and 8080 port have already be used. So I click the config button(like first picture) and select my.ini(server.xml) file to change the port 3306（8080).And I restart the Xampp program,find the same problem have still exist.Finally I click the config button(like second picture) change the port agaig and restart the Xampp program and I success slove the problem. [first.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK8iw.png)[second.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3CjP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat7 in XAMPP wouldn't start and uninstall of the service throws:

> Tomcat Service Uninstall stopped with errors, return code: 3

so, open cmd as Administrator and manually remove the service:

> - C:\Windows\system32> sc delete "Tomcat7"
> - [SC] DeleteService SUCCESS

close & open xampp control; you will see Tomcat service with a red cross mark. Now everything starts to work.

Answer (score 0):

Install latest version of JDK and set environmental variable as follow:

Variable name: JAVA_HOME
Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues with tomcat in XAMPP just yesterday and i've tried something that solve the problem.

1. Go to XAMPP Directory / tomcat
2. Shift + Right click on empty space > run command windows here
3. type "catalina_start" or whatever the bat for starting catalina named there
4. Look at the report in the cmd that it gave you

In my case, the error is " The JRE_HOME is not Defined " in Environment Variables, so

1. I go to : right click PC in explorer > Properties > Advanced SystemSetting
2. Go to Environment Variables
3. Check the existence of JRE_HOME in User and System Variable
4. Click New on User Variables > Name : JRE_HOME > Value : Browse directory my JRE is in
5. Click New on System Variables > Name : JRE_HOME > Value : Browse directory my JRE is in
6. I restart XAMPP
7. Start tomcat in XAMPP
8. Celebrate

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\
```

That is where Java is installed

Then open a new port in Firewall and change that same port at `server.xml` in directory

```
c:\xampp\tomcat\conf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to change the Environmental Variables and it fails, then, you can search for **services** on windows and restart **tomcat** manually through its tomcat service action, and set it to automatically.

...You are done...

its that simple

emmhphanzzy

Answer (score 0):

Yes dipo you can manually start Tomcat by running the catalina_startup.bat file after you make sure that you have installed the JRE, JDK, placed those paths in your JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables and made sure that the ports are clear as Vyacheslav and others have explained.

However, in order to have XAMPP bring Tomcat server up automatically you need to  add your tomcat directory to your Path environment variable and omit the "\bin" sub path. Tomcat should start without any problems once you do this.  The problem in my case was that the search patch didn't go deep enough when I had used  C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-8.0.24\bin  so it missed seeing and running the catalina_starup.bat file. Thus I had to click on the catalina_startup.bat fiel to run it manually and then it made sense for me to go back and remove that \bin sub path.

Answer (score 0):

Go to environment variables, In system variables add

1. variable_name: `CATALINA_HOME`

variable_value: **C:\xampp\tomcat**

2. variable_name: `JAVA_HOME`

variable_value: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92**(Upto your jdk path in your system)

Now go to the **C:\xampp\tomcat**

shift+right click and choose open command window here and type `catalina_start` then hit enter

Now to go the xampp contorl panel and start tomacat